# Opening Outlook conversations without marking them as read using the VBA MarkAsUnread function

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Assume you grouped your Outlook messages by conversation. How to prevent any mail from a conversation to get marked ***read*** when double clicking on a conversation's main header?

Code I came up with so far:

1. I use `Application_ItemLoad` to get the object of any selected mail
2. Then, `myItem_Read` to store the selected mail's `UnRead` property because it's not accessible yet at the time of `ItemLoad`
3. Finally, I listen on the `PropertyChange` event to change back any read mail to *unread*. However, in the **else** branch below the expression `mySelection.Item(1).GetConversation.MarkAsUnread` fails unexpectedly. From my understanding, `mySelection.Item(1)` selects the Conversation Header object. Then I try to obtain its Conversation object using `GetConversation`and call the `MarkAsUnread` method which should in theory mark all the conversation's messages as ***unread*** again. Just theory. And I don't know why.

### 1.

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.mailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Set myItem = Item
     End If
End Sub
```

### 2.

```
Private Sub myItem_Read()
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    unReadWhenSelected = myItem.UnRead
End Sub
```

### 3.

```
Private Sub myItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    Dim mySelection As Selection
    Dim oConvHeader As Outlook.ConversationHeader
    Dim oConv As Outlook.Conversation

    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub

    If Name = "UnRead" Then
        If unReadWhenSelected = True And myItem.UnRead = False Then

            Set mySelection = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders)


            If mySelection.Count = 0 Then

                myItem.UnRead = True
                myItem.Save

            Else         
                mySelection.Item(1).GetConversation.MarkAsUnread

            End If

        End If
    End If    
End Sub
```

**Whole story for interested readers:**
Let's say you wanted to open a conversation by double clicking its header without the conversation's elements getting marked as *read*.
I want to use Outlook E-Mails as tasks and change the meaning of a reading a mail to finishing a task. Thus, I use search folders with the option "only show unread messages". As soon as I finish a task, I just mark it read with a macro.
For all the other cases where I just want to read the mails etc. they need to remain unread.

I wrote a macro to accomplish this for single E-Mail messages which are not part of conversations. When it comes to conversations, this macro works for all its elements - but not for the first one also known as the main conversation's header entry.

### Edit:

Proof-of-concept code for marking all emails in a conversation as *read*. 
Why is this not working in my example code above?

```
Sub Testorino()

    Dim mySelection As Selection
    Set mySelection = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders)
    mySelection.Item(1).GetConversation.MarkAsUnread

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use tasks for the same purpose? It would seem that might be easier to manage instead of the read property. Alternately, you could move the email to a separate "completed task" folder

Comment: You are trying to keep the whole conversation unread? and which office are you using?

Comment: @seadoggie01 I tried tasks before but decided for just mails for this solution. Your idea is nice but I want to actually solve the riddle I got here ;)

Comment: @0m3r Office 365, Outlook has Version 1919. Yes, I want to mark the whole conversation unread. I will add the proof of concept code that does exactly this. But in my scenario it doesn't work for no apparent reason.

Comment: I'll have to take a look on Monday when I get back to work then :) We use a similar concept for items in a shared inbox

Comment: I also found out that my proof of concept code (see bottom of my initial posting) does work in my original code as well. But what I have just grasped is that after marking all mails of the conversation as _unread_ the most recent (top) element of the conversation is opened marking all its mails as _read_ again. My existing event handlers do not catch it and hence cannot restore the ```UnRead``` property. Tried the ```myItem_open``` event but this doesn't catch it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: MS says this shouldn't be done at all. Application.ItemLoad's items are not intended to be used again. Note the warning here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemload
It says:

> The Item object passed in this event should not be cached for any use outside the scope of this event.

You should be able to use the `Items.ItemChange` and `Items.Add` events instead (after initially setting it to the Inbox's items) and ignore every unread change unless your macro started it.

---

Old Answer --> This seems to work in Outlook 2016 in the conversation view. When the item is closed, mark the conversation as unread. This way, it doesn't skip the first item as you mentioned in your comment. If this interferes with your macro, I can see if I can get it to work after opening the item, but I wasn't getting far with that.

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim EventsDisable As Boolean
Dim UnreadWhenSelected As Boolean

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print ("Item_Load")
            Set myItem = Item
     End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print ("Item_Close")
    If UnreadWhenSelected Then
        ' Ignore all events fired while marking the conversation as unread
        EventsDisable = True
        myItem.GetConversation.MarkAsUnread
        EventsDisable = False
    Else
        ' Ignore all events fired while marking the conversation as read
        EventsDisable = True
        myItem.GetConversation.MarkAsRead
        EventsDisable = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Read()
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    UnreadWhenSelected = myItem.UnRead
    Debug.Print ("Item_Read. Unread: " & UnreadWhenSelected)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this is already pretty good. If I add ```myItem.UnRead = True``` to the ```If UnreadWhenSelected``` branch I have the same behavior for single mails and mails as part of a conversation. Then I can even skip your Else branch. But, I really wonder why this can't be done in the ```myItem_Open``` event as this would be better for my purpose. I am curious if you can find out if that's possible.

Comment: Just found out that for some reason for single messages this doesn't work consistently. For this I added ```myItem.UnRead = True``` after ```myItem.GetConversation.MarkAsUnread```.

Comment: @MartinLundberg I updated my answer. Sorry for not responding sooner, I need to mess with my notification settings :)

Comment: And one more note... you might be able to change your reading pane options manually if this is just for you. (File->Options->Mail->Outlook Panes->Reading Pane) If it's not, the Outlook options are stored in the Registry somewhere :|

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately, I could not make it work for my scenario because I use search folders and have no clue how to link Items.ItemChange to a search folder. Do you have any idea how to use this in search folders? +1 because it actually works for my InBox :)

Comment: I've never actually heard of search folders. I'll see what I can find out though!

Comment: You can find search folders by enumerating `Application.Stores` -> `Store` and `Store.GetSearchFolders` -> `SearchFolder`. I'm not sure if my code works with this though